# what's wrong with my hadoop configuration?

Tags: hadoop

I've done all the work that hadoop requires, but there seems something wrong with it, for example:

I have a class Hello.class, when I use the command "java Hello" it works correctly, but when I try to use the command "hadoop Hello" it reports that "cannot load or find the main class", but when I use "jar" command to change Hello.class into Hello.jar, however, I use the command "hadoop jar Hello.jar Hello", this time it works correctly just as I used the command "java Hello"

What is wrong with my configuration?

In file etc/profile the following has been added:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk1.7.0_04
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/hadoop-1.0.1
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export CLASS_PATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
```

I've added "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk1.7.0_04" into file "hadoop-env.sh"

I've changed core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, mapred-site.xml accordingly

Is there anyone having the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hadoop Hello` command runs hadoop and looks for a class named Hello on the current classpath - which doesn't contain your class.

Bundling your class into a jar and running `hadoop jar myjar.jar Hello` tells hadoop to add the jar file myjar.jar to the classpath and then run the class named Hello (which is now on the classpath)

If you want to add a class to the classpath configure the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` environment variable